# Reactive patterns with argument preconditions

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm working with RxJava and I don't know where the right place to check arguments would be. For example, say I have the following:

```
public Completable createDirectory(final String path) {
    return Completable.create(emitter -> {
        final File directory = new File(path);
        final boolean createdSuccessfully = directory.mkDirs();

        if (createdSuccessfully) {
            emitter.onComplete();
        } else {
            emitter.onError(new IOException("Failed to create directory.");
        }
    }
}
```

Would it be better to check for a null path in the root of the method, or at the start of the completable? I'm leaning towards the former, but I'm interested in the pros and cons of both approaches.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, at least have the decency to explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say: it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

If you check for null-value on method-entry, before Completeable.create, you would throw the NPE/ IllegalArgumentException on calling-thread. This would follow the 'fail fast'-philosophy. Possible pros:
* fails fast on method-invocation
* Exception in callstack of calling-thread

If you check in Completable.create-lambda, it will be invoked on lambda-evaluation (subscription).

Example: Call createDirectory-Method on calling-thread, add subscribeOn and subscribe: NPE / IllegalArgumentException will be thrown on subscribeOn-Scheduler-Thread on subscription.

It will only be thrown, when you subscribe to returned Completable. Maybe you create an Completable but never subscribe to it. Then no exception will be thrown. This could be a pro for checking in lambda. If you would not check, a NPE would be thrown anyways on subscribeOn thread. Exception thrown on subscribeOn thread could be negative, because you only see the trace for subscribedOn-thread. Sometimes it is not easy to see the flow, when switching threads with only on callstack. You would not see that createDirectory-method was invoked. You would only see the lambda invocation plus some reactive-stack-polution.

I would say: use fail fast, if you subscribe to created Completable at some point. If it is possible, that no subscription to created Completable happens at any time, it would probably use some Precondition with a message, because it will only throw, when subscribed to (lazy). Anyways, if you check with Objects#requireNonNull() without any message in the lambda, you could just discard checking for null, because the NPE will be thrown anyway.